# JavaScript set cell values while cloning rows of a table does not work in some IE browsers

Tags: javascript, html, cell

The following function is working fine in IE 11 version 11.309.16299.0, but not in IE 11 version 11.0.9600.18499.
It looks like 'cells[]' does not work.If I remove all the 'cells[]', it is working on both versions IE.
any idea why 'cells[]' is not working for some IE version?

Thanks.

```
function insRow()
{
var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
var len = x.rows.length;
new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
theName1 = 'OtherAreas'+ len;
theName2 = 'SFootage'+ len;
theName3 = 'YBuilt'+ len;

var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
inp1.id += len;
inp1.setAttribute('name', theName1);
inp1.value = '';
var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inp2.id += len;
inp2.setAttribute('name', theName2);
inp2.value = '';
 var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inp3.id += len;
inp3.setAttribute('name', theName3);
inp3.value = '';
x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```